# Downloading Secondary Domain User Documents Google Document List Api 2-Legged Oauth

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

First post so sorry for any formatting issues.

I am trying to download a secondary domain user's documents via oauth and receiving a com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized error.  I am able to pull the users document using a feed call similar to this :

```
String docUrl = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/" + DOC_OWNER + "/private/full/" + DOC_ID + "?xoauth_requestor_id="+ PRIMARY_ADMIN_EMAIL
DocumentListEntry googleDoc = docServ.getEntry(new URL(docUrl), DocumentListEntry.class);
String exportUrl = ((MediaContent) googleDoc.getContent()).getUri().toString();
exportString = ((MediaContent) googleDoc.getContent()).getUri().split("&xoauth_requestor_id=")[0];
exportString + EXPORT_TYPE // add export type
```

but then when trying to download the document such as :

```
MediaContent mc = new MediaContent();
mc.setUri(exportUrl);
String mcUrl = mc.getUri() + "&xoauth_requestor_id=" + DOC_OWNER;
MediaSource ms = docServ.getMedia(mc);
```

This throws the authentication exception.  I have tried swapping out the requestor id for the primary domain admin with no success.  I have also tried using user creds for the primary domain admin and that throws a service forbidden exception. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the domain's OAuth key/secret don't have access to secondary domains. You need to manually enter the key (primary domain) and the Docs API scopes:

https://docs.google.com/feeds/,https://docs.googleusercontent.com/,https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/

at:

https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE/ManageOauthClients

for it to work with secondary domain accounts.